# Are there any cases where LDA/GGA overestimates band gaps? If so what is the reason?

Tags: density-functional-theory

It is well known that LDA/GGA often underestimates band gaps. So I wonder if there are any cases where LDA/GGA overestimates the band gap?

In these cases, what is the reason?

Answer (score 13):

First, it's worth noting that DFT with both LDA or GGA **underestimate** band gap and not overestimate it usually. In extreme cases, it predicts that your compound is metal (i.e. no band gap at all)!

The reason is that there is a discontinuity in the derivative of energy with respect to number of electrons. Both LDA and GGA suffers from this problem. One example is band gap of $\text{La}_{2}\text{CuO}_{4}$ a high temperature superconductor with band gap of 2 eV but LDA, PBE, and PW91 predict it as a metal! ref: [Perry et. al.](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.63.144510)

More reads here:

- [Yakovkin and Dowben](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0218625X07009499)
- [Xiao et. al.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jz101565j)

**Update**: If you are looking for a case that DFT with GGA or LDA overestimate the band gap and if you consider PBE (Perdew–Burke-Ernzerhof) exchange-correlation as a part of GGA, yes there are couple of examples that band gap is overestimated for compounds of $\text{PbSe}$ and $\text{Bi}_{2}\text{Se}_{3}$ because there is a strong spin-orbit coupling in these compounds with small band gap[4](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.jpclett.5b02870).

Comment: It seems that the question acknowledges that it's "well known" that LDA/GGA under-estimate band gaps, and they are asking for examples where LDA/GGA over-estimates the band gap. Do you concur?

Comment: Thank you for the update. It would also be interesting if there's any examples without spin-orbit coupling, since regular DFT isn't meant for dealing with spin-orbit coupling.

Comment: @Alone Programmer, I'm sorry that the question is not directly related to the topic, but I was very interested in your statement. You wrote that the band gap of LaCuO is about 2 eV. However, how can this satisfy the well-known formula https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/892886856b8f0a8d8036328f831d188a6dc10aee relating the band gap to the critical temperature? In the best case, the critical temperature is 40K.